# Autowiring in Junit

Tags: java, junit, autowired

I am trying to autowire two objects from the context but seems to be getting Nullpointer exception on both of `Configuraiton` and `JavaMailSender`, what could I be possible missing. If I am autowiring just `EmailService`, it works correctly however I need to pass a mock object to the constructor which is why I am proceeding the way I am now. If I annotate my `EmailService` object with `@Autowire`, it works.

```
@SpringBootTest

    public class EmailServiceTest {

        @Autowired
        private Configuration configuration;

        @Autowired
        private JavaMailSender javaMailSender;

        private AuthUser authUser = Mockito.mock(AuthUser.class);

        private EmailService emailService = new EmailService(javaMailSender,configuration,authUser);


 @Test
public void testSendAttachment() throws IOException {
    List<Attachment> attachments = new ArrayList<>();
    attachments.add(new Attachment(new Archive(TestData.getDocs(), "test").getZipArchive(), "documents.zip"));
    attachments.add(new Attachment(new Archive(TestData.getDocs(), "test").getZipArchive(), "documents2.zip"));
    Email mail = new Email("a",
            "b",
            "Requested archive attached",
            "Thank you for using our services, please refer to the attached archive", attachments);
    emailService.sendMailWithAttachment(mail);

}

  @Test
public void shouldSendConfirmationEmail(){
    Mockito.when(authUser.getUsername()).thenReturn("email@email.com");
    emailService.sendConfirmationToCooperateEmail();
}
```

Comment: You can annotate `authUser` with `@MockBean` instead of manually mocking it and rest of the varaibles can be marked `@Autowired`.

Comment: @Smile I found the reason, thank you also for pointing it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring creates EmailServiceTest.java
Properties Configuration and EmailService are null by default
as we initialize EmailService right on property
Email service GET null values immediately and only then Spring injects values to Configuration and EmailSender.

```
 @Autowired
private Configuration configuration;

@Autowired
private JavaMailSender javaMailSender;

private AuthUser authUser = Mockito.mock(AuthUser.class);


@Test
public void testSendAttachment() throws IOException {
    EmailService emailService = new EmailService(javaMailSender, configuration, authUser);
```